# How to Link and use two or more Dropbox Accounts simultaneously

Tags: file-sharing, dropbox

I have two Dropbox accounts. Is it possible to link and use both of the accounts simultaneously **without logging in as the different user?**

Do not confuse with similar looking post

> [Multiple Dropbox accounts on the same computer for different users](https://askubuntu.com/q/264271/127327).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**General idea** <sup>[[source](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/run-multiple-instances-of-dropbox-simultaneously-on-linux-or-mac-os-x)]</sup>

> The basic idea is to just start Dropbox from the command-line using an alternate home directory. This will create another Dropbox icon, and another Dropbox folder, which has to be in some other place from the original one.
>
> The two Dropbox folders will both be called Dropbox (this cannot be changed), but you can distinguish them by their location.

[image]

## Setup

### [Method: 1](https://askubuntu.com/a/393846/127327) - If you have installed `nautilus-dropbox` [from the repository](https://askubuntu.com/a/393846/127327)

Open a terminal and paste the following commands:

```
$ mkdir "$HOME"/.dropbox-alt 
$ HOME="$HOME/.dropbox-alt"
$ /usr/bin/dropbox start -i
```

A new Dropbox setup wizard window will open and second Dropbox icon should appear on the status bar.

- Choose an existing account (different from the original one!) or create a new one.
- Make sure you choose an alternate location for your new Dropbox folder.

Now your alternate dropbox is set.

**start Dropbox from terminal**

```
$ /usr/bin/dropbox start -i
```

**start Alternate-Dropbox from terminal**

```
$ HOME="$HOME/.dropbox-alt" && /usr/bin/dropbox start -i
```

### [Method: 2](https://askubuntu.com/a/237655/127327) - If you have compiled `dropbox` in your home [from `tar.gz` file](https://askubuntu.com/a/237655/127327)

Open a terminal and paste the following commands:

```
$ mkdir "$HOME"/.dropbox-alt
$ ln -s "$HOME/.Xauthority" "$HOME/.dropbox-alt/"
$ HOME="$HOME/.dropbox-alt"
$ /home/$USER/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

Dropbox setup wizard window will appear. Finish the setup similarly as described in Method -1

**start Dropbox from terminal**

```
$ /home/$USER/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

**start Alternate-Dropbox from terminal**

```
$ HOME="$HOME/.dropbox-alt" && /home/$USER/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

### Note:

- You can create a small script with the above commands to start Dropbox.
- One can put the script at startup. **Don't forget to give the script execution permission.**

```
chmod +x /path/to/script
```

- I have tested the second method. Hope it will be useful.

Comment: The first method worked nicely for me Ubuntu 14.04.  Just two notes: this answer assumes you've already gone ahead and linked your first Dropbox account.  Second, when you're linking your account with the Dropbox GUI and you want to change the location, you have to click `Advanced Settings` which appears on the screen after you choose your selective sync options.

Comment: For me, I was able to have the two folders in the same location, because my second one (business account) had a different name.  It seems the second one's default name must have been set by my admin, so maybe that only applies to business accounts.

Comment: This is no longer working for me.  Starting the second Dropbox instance kills the first one.  (on Ubuntu 14.04.2 with kernel 3.16.0-13)

Comment: @Garrett - if this stops working for you, try this: https://realflash.wordpress.com/2016/02/11/multiple-dropboxes-stops-working-only-one-at-a-time/

Comment: what's this got to do with `nautilus`?

Comment: The second approach also works with the default `.deb` provided for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

The multiple fake home directories method works until Dropbox updates itself; if you find that you have this working and then it stops working, see https://realflash.wordpress.com/2016/02/11/multiple-dropboxes-stops-working-only-one-at-a-time/