# Run Multiple Instances of Dropbox Simultaneously on Ubuntu

Tags: dropbox

I want to run my personal and business Dropbox accounts simultaneously on Ubuntu 14.04. This is a common dropbox function under Windows and Mac, but inexplicably Dropbox refuses to implement it for Linux.

Yes, I am aware that this has been asked and answered before. I have run my two Dropbox accounts simultaneously for years with only minor tweaks, but since maybe 2 or 3 months ago it has stopped working and I can't find a fix. These 3 links have been my guidance, but they are 2-5 years old, and I suspect something has changed recently:

http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/run-multiple-instances-of-dropbox-simultaneously-on-linux-or-mac-os-x#On_Ubuntu

[How to Link and use two or more Dropbox Accounts simultaneously](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475419/how-to-link-and-use-two-or-more-dropbox-accounts-simultaneously)

https://realflash.wordpress.com/2016/02/11/multiple-dropboxes-stops-working-only-one-at-a-time/

Every time I start one Dropbox account, it overrides and kills the execution of the other account.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, kernel 4.4.0-128. I may have two Dropbox versions:

1) v52.4.58. This is the version I see at the GUI and in folders at:

$HOME/.dropbox-dist

$HOME/.dropbox-Account_1/.dropbox-dist

$HOME/.dropbox-Account_2/.dropbox-dist

2) However, in the folder $HOME/.dropbox-dist there is another folder named after version 51.4.66.

I am pretty sure (not 100%, sorry) that I installed Dropbox via the Binary Distribution:

cd ~ && wget -O - "http://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xz

But I am happy to try other installation sources, I just need this to work!

Thanks!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Did you read my message? On it, I posted the same link you suggest and I explained that it's not working for me anymore. Not only did you send me to read the link I had already shared, but you flagged my question as a duplicate based on that same link...  
Why would someone haste to do this? is there a price for being the first to comment or flag a question?

Comment: It's not intentional, my apologies!